# Get a dictionary of lists from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, datagridview

I have the following data in a datagridview:

[image]

My objective is to get a dictionary `<FeatureName, List<PropertyName>>`. So for the picture shown it should have three entries with the key-value pairs:

```
{ Speed, {protocol} }

{Fan, {Protocol, lowPWM} }

{Grade, {Protocol, limits} }
```

So far I got the checkedrows with the code below:

`var checkedRows = this.configDiffDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                      .Where(row => (bool?)row.Cells[4].Value == true)
                      .ToList();`

And got started trying to get the dictionary out of the checked rows with the code below:

`var groupsByFeature = checkedRows.GroupBy(r => r.Cells["Feature Name"].Value);`

But can't figure out how to make it work. Please help and if you think there's a better approach I am open to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lookup<string, string>` is similar to `Dictionary<string, string[]>`:

```
ILookup<string, string> lookup = configDiffDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => true.Equals(r.Cells[4].Value))
    .ToLookup(r => r.Cells[0].Value as string, r => r.Cells[1].Value as string);

Debug.Print(string.Join(",", lookup["Fan"])); // "Protocol,lowPWM"
```

---

Dictionary version that avoids some of the LINQ overhead and casting (also not tested):

```
var dgv = this.configDiffDataGridView;               
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (true.Equals(dgv[4, i].Value))           // to avoid Exception when Value is not bool
    {
        string key = dgv[0, i].Value as string; // or Value?.ToString() for non-string types
        List<string> list;

        if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out list))   // if not found, create and add
        {
            list = new List<string>(2);         // adjust capacity to the average # of items
            dict.Add(key, list);
        }
        list.Add(dgv[1, i].Value as string);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved the hard part of what I needed. I edited the answer to convert the lookup to a dictionary and get exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Slai

Comment: @JcAlmonte If you don't need to add items to it, there is no reason to convert it to dictionary as the group values [are already stored in array](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,eba6ce0eb1bb3acc). Also, `lookup["some value that doesn't exist"]` returns empty result instead of Exception. If you really need a Dictionary, I can give you a better answer, but the conversion is `var dict = lookup.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList())`

Comment: Your answer is what I was looking for. I don't really need a dictionary, I just preferred to use one because of familiarity. For the sake of learning, would you add the "better" answer as if i strictly needed a dictionary? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what ur looking for (you have to create new object from group by)

```
checkedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().GroupBy(item => item.Cells[Feature Name].Value)
 .Select(group => new { FeatureName = group.Key, Properties = group.Cells["Property Name].Value.ToList() })
 .ToList()
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting an error in the `Select` clause on `group.Cells["Property Name"]` because `group` does not contain a definition for `Cells`

Comment: Try `item` instead of `cells`

Comment: I tried that too but, `item` is not defined for `group`. Also tried doing `item.Cells` but `item` is not accessible in the select clause